# Get value of the property in all the array list c#

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, windows-phone-7

How to get the value of the property which is in array list? I tried the following code but am getting something like, System.Linq.Enumerable like that. I need to get the values of the property in all the list in that array.

```
sampleClass.Add(new ClassProp()
        {
            NameAttributes = listDetails.Select(x=>x.FirstName).ToString()

        });
```

listDetails is the list of arry list. NameAttributes is the string property.

Comment: `listDetails` may contain multiple items, hence there could be multiple `FirstName` values. What you expect the `NameAttributes` value in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `string.Join`

```
NameAttributes = string.Join("," ,listDetails.Select(x=>x.FirstName));
```

Comment: That's cool. But am binding NameAttributes to list where am generating the list with respect to the count of array list and display those values. Can you help me in that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `NameAttributes` is e.g. `IEnumerable<string>` then

```
sampleClass.Add(new ClassProp()
  {
    NameAttributes = (from MyClass x in arrayList select x.MyProperty).ToList()
  });
```

Comment: No dude, I get the value as {System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator<PhoneApp.Model.ClassProp,string>}

Comment: I was going to ask why but seems like you already got your answer.